# Setting locale into application scope

Tags: locale, mate-panel

I want my default date format to be iso8601 but I want my desktop panel clock to use a 12-hour display.

For this preference, the MATE panel clock applet wants a session language that includes a 12-hour clock.

To get the iso format, the recommendation is for en_DK and this, apparently, does not offer a 12-hour clock.

How can I give the clock applet a locale with a 12-hour clock and keep the iso format everywhere else?

I suppose I could set the bash session to en_DK and then applications run in that session will inherit that locale? But I prefer to make it a panel-specific locale.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to modify your panel launch arguments to include the environment variable, like so:

```
LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8 mate-panel
```

The `LC_TIME` will be isolated to mate-panel and its processes only.

Comment: I took the locale from one of my laptops in which the feature is working and posted it as you suggest. (Replaced the command with a script) Unfortunately it doesn't change the event. A glance at the code suggests that the clock applet takes its locale from system not from session so...